# Openwrt in bridge mode - ebtables kernel error

Tags: networking, iptables, openwrt, bridge-router

I have a setup at home as follow:

```
DHCP clients  -----> (wifi)(bridge) Openwrt -----> (eth)Main Router
```

The device I'm using is TPlink MR3020 with Barrier Breaker and I tried to set up transparent proxy for bridge traffic - I want to redirect the packets passing through the bridge to proxy server(`privoxy`). I tried to use `ebtables`. But when I enter the following command:

```
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p IPv4 --ip-protocol 6 --ip-destination-port 80 -j redirect --redirect-target ACCEPT
```

I got following error:

```
Unable to update the kernel. Two possible causes:
1. Multiple ebtables programs were executing simultaneously. The ebtables
userspace tool doesn't by default support multiple ebtables programs running
concurrently. The ebtables option --concurrent or a tool like flock can be
used to support concurrent scripts that update the ebtables kernel tables.
2. The kernel doesn't support a certain ebtables extension, consider
recompiling your kernel or insmod the extension.
```

I tried to activate the IPv4 package with `insmod`, but no luck.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

That error message usually results from missing kernel modules.  The correct syntax and order for loading the ones you need should be:

`insmod ebtables` #load ebtables

`insmod ebtable_filter` #load filter table [ not strictly necessary ]

`insmod ebtable_broute` #load broute table

`insmod ebt_ip` #load ip filtering

`insmod ebt_redirect` #load redirect

`lsmod` #check that they are active

Comment: Thank you, but there is no luck. I tried to do what you said, but I take `Failed to find ebt_ip. Maybe it is a built in module ? ` error. I tried to find this module before, but I couldn't find. Do you know how can I overcome this error ?

Comment: If you see it in the output of `find / -iname "*ebt*"` then you can `insmod` with full path.  If it is not there you need to find the appropriate module for your kernel and add it manually.